# Setting a graphics card limit for slurm partitions

Tags: gpu, limit, slurm, partition, hpc

I have a problem with slurm partition.
In order to be able to manage my users, I created the following 4 types of partitions:

```
PartitionName=small State=UP Nodes=ALL MaxTime=INFINITE MaxNodes=2 DefMemPerNode=32000 MaxMemPerNode=32000 MaxCPUsPerNode=16 Default=YES
PartitionName=medium State=UP Nodes=ALL MaxTime=INFINITE MaxNodes=2 DefMemPerNode=64000 MaxMemPerNode=64000 MaxCPUsPerNode=32
PartitionName=large State=UP Nodes=ALL MaxTime=INFINITE MaxNodes=3 DefMemPerNode=128000 MaxMemPerNode=128000 MaxCPUsPerNode=64
PartitionName=entire State=UP Nodes=ALL MaxTime=INFINITE MaxNodes=INFINITE MaxMemPerNode=INFINITE MaxCPUsPerNode=INFINITE
```

I would also like to be able to add a graphics card limit to each partition.

What is the best way to do this?

Now I want to say that the users of each partition have a graphics card limit as follows:

- small and medium partitions: 1 GPU
- partition size: 2 GPUs
- partition entire: no limitation

At first, I thought it was easy to use Gres like running a job, but there is no such key at all. I saw all the documents and did not find a key similar to what I want. In fact, the reason for this is that the users in each partition have unlimited graphics cards, and the users of the small partition occupy all the graphics cards, and I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be done by creating [Partition QOSes](https://slurm.schedmd.com/qos.html#partition) for each partition and setting a limit on `GrpTRES=gres/gpu=2` for instance.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Yes, I was also trying to solve it with qos.
I just didn't pay attention that in order to use qos and apply it, I have to set this:
AccountingStorageEnforce=associations,limits,qos,safe

My problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, after some time I came across this error. What do you think is the reason?
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid account or account/partition combination specified